# Getting "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<)" .Net 6

Tags: url, routes, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service, .net-6.0

I found so much of answers in ASP.Net MVC with simple fix of including validateRequest tag in web.config 
 Do I need to follow the same for .Net Core 6 as well (adding web.config) ? 
 no reference are found for .Net 6. 
 My exact problem:
`http://.....com/aisv3/admin/'<'svg onload='abc'>` 

This invalid request leads to VAPT issue, that has to be redirected to my own error page instead of default error message. Please suggest.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you host the application? Inside the IIS or else? Besides, we don't suggest you to allow this character inside the request, it will cause security issue.

Comment: hosted in Azure. Actual Url  'https://assetinsightservice.azurewebsites.net/aisv3dev%3Csvg%20onload='sdf'%3E'